# How to apply datetime to a column within a dataframe that is stored in a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, metatrader5

I have managed to create a dictionary of dataframes but am unsure of how i can convert the time column to datetime as i always get an error. I have selected the data with  :

```
for k, v in rates.items():

    print(v['time'])
```

Do i need to change dictionary back to dataframe and then do this ?.The code has date time object but i cant seem to get it done here. I thought it would just convert them..

```
rates['time']=pd.to_datetime(rates['time'], unit='s')
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon May 25 00:34:03 2020

@author: DanPc
"""

import pytz
import pandas as pd
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Timer
import talib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

server_name = "ICMarkets-MT5"
server_num = 
password = ""



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def actualtime():
    # datetime object containing current date and time
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    #print("date and time =", dt_string)
    return str(dt_string)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def sync_60sec(op):

    info_time_new = datetime.strptime(str(actualtime()), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    waiting_time = 60 - info_time_new.second

    t = Timer(waiting_time, op)
    t.start()

    print(actualtime)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def program(symbol):
    if not mt5.initialize(login=server_num, server=server_name, password=password):
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()


# set time zone to UTC
timezone = pytz.timezone("Etc/UTC")
# create 'datetime' object in UTC time zone to avoid the implementation of a local time zone offset
utc_from = datetime(2020, 1, 10, tzinfo=timezone)
    
   # Create currency watchlist for which correlation matrix is to be plotted

sym = ["GBPUSD","USDJPY","USDCHF","AUDUSD","GBPJPY"]


# Copying data to dataframe

utc_from = datetime.now()
for i in sym:
     rates = {i:pd.DataFrame(mt5.copy_rates_from(i, mt5.TIMEFRAME_M1, utc_from ,  10), 
             columns=['time', 'open', 'low', 'high', 'close', 'tick_volume', 'spread', 'real_volume']).drop(['tick_volume','spread','real_volume'], axis=1)for i in sym}

for k, v in rates.items():
    
    print(v['time'])


    
if not mt5.initialize():
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()         
    
   
  
    
mt5.shutdown()


  
if not mt5.initialize():
        print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
        quit()

         
# starting mt5
if not mt5.initialize(login=server_num, server=server_name, password=password):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =",mt5.last_error())
    quit()          
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                   S T A R T I N G   M T 5 
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
authorized=mt5.login(server_num, password=password)
if authorized:
    account_info=mt5.account_info()
    if account_info!=None:       
        account_info_dict = mt5.account_info()._asdict()
        df=pd.DataFrame(list(account_info_dict.items()),columns=['property','value'])
        print("account_info() as dataframe:")
        print(df)
else:
    print(mt5.last_error)

mt5.shutdown()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def trading_bot():
    symbol_1 = 'EURUSD'
    
    while True:
        program(symbol_1)
        time.sleep(59.8) # it depends on your computer and ping

sync_60sec(trading_bot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to convert `rates` to a data frame with column `time`.

I think you are confused between dictionary and data frame here. I guess the confusion is because a data frame is a **dictionary of columns**, right?

So for clarification, a dictionary is a set of pairs (k, v), where v can be anything from a number to a structured object. In your case, unless your v is an object where `v[time]` is valid, e.g. it is a dictionary with key `time`, you will have problem.

FYI, a dictionary of data frames is a really complicated data structure :).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply I still dont really understand. I get that I have a dictionary and key / values and the value is the dataframe? and I select 'time'within that value to view that column?. It seemed like a good thing to do for feature engineering in ML but I have no idea :)

Comment: I read about using baskets in ML so thought dictionary of dataframes is the only way?.

Answer (score 0):

If each value is a DF then you are doing correct. But when you do date time conversion, it seems you are doing it on the whole dictionary `rates`, which is wrong. You need to do that on each value instead. So use a for loop on the values, or a `map` to apply the conversion to each value.

Comment: Okay, why post a second answer instead of editing your first? Do you want to be upvoted twice? It doesn't work like that. . .

Comment: Hi cs95, no need to up vote twice, I just accidentally write another answer because I’m doing it on my phone

Comment: Hi, im still struggling to understand it to be honest but will keep thinking about it. if you could provide an example that would be helpful. I'm trying something like this now    for v in rates.items():
                                                                              v[1]['time'][0]

Comment: Try this: `for k, v in rates.items(): v['time'] = pd.to_datetime(v['time'])`.

Comment: Thanks for your help really appreciate it.  v['time'] = pd.to_datetime(v['time'], unit='s')

Comment: ofcourse but I have less then 15 reputation so they are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: oh I got it, no worry